# Return all records within given date

Tags: sql-server

### Question

How do I return all records from today until a given number of days in the future?

### Example in pseudo code

```
Select every record from table 
where plandate = today and the next 14 days
```

### What I have tried?

```
select *
from joblist
WHERE  plandate >= GETDATE() +14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DATEADD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx):

```
WHERE  plandate >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
AND    plandate < DATEADD(day,+15, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Note that you have the [`Date` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) only if you use at least SQL-Server 2008.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this: (I'm omitting declares)

```
set @today = GETDATE()
set @endDate = DATEADD(DAY,15,GETDATE())

SELECT your_Records from TABLE
WHERE plandate >= @today
AND plandate < @endDate
```

You can also use the BETWEEN clause:

```
SELECT your_Records from TABLE
WHERE plandate BETWEEN @today AND @endDate
```

Comment: Came back to this post after ages and found out the server i wanted to use was a 2005 box, so thank you for this alternative.